# Move/Add Favorites Tab to Homepage

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

To access your favorites, the current process is to go to your user profile, and then access the favorites tab down the bottom of the page.

This requires two steps, and the favorites tab is quiet hard to spot, as the heading is small, and its buried in with other options.

I suggest that it should be a little easier for a user to access their favorites. Possible places to add it would be on the top nav bar, or sidebar.

[image]

Not a huge issue, but it would improve the user experience of the site a little.